# How services can facilitate development of UI Layer for Webview based Hybrid App?

Tags: user-interface, service, webview, hybrid

I'm learning android and I wanted to know about the advantages of services about android applications for web based apps.

**How services can facilitate development of UI Layer for Webview based Hybrid App?**

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

[As you can see in this article][1] that WebView requires attention of code fragments and screen resolution to run on different devices. So, rerendering the data using services can increase the performance of ui exponentially.

[1]: [https://www2.stardust-testing.com/en/blog-en/hybrid-apps#:~:text=%2D%20Calling%20a%20WebView,to%20be%20widened](https://www2.stardust-testing.com/en/blog-en/hybrid-apps#:%7E:text=%2D%20Calling%20a%20WebView,to%20be%20widened)).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).